# Application is not starting in interactive mode

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, console-application

I am trying to start notepad from console application using process.start() . Notepad is opening too but it is in background. As soon as I close my console app It launches.
Below is my code. I have tried opening it in main thread and in separate thread as well.
Suggest me ways to open notepad or other program in interactive mode without being blocked.

Kindly help me

```
 static void RunApplication()
            {
                Process proc = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe",
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,

                    },
                };
                proc.OutputDataReceived += App_OutputDataReceived;
                proc.ErrorDataReceived += App_ErrorDataReceived;
                proc.Start();
                proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

                RunCommand(proc, @"C:");
                RunCommand(proc, @"notepad.exe");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

            }



    static void RunCommand(Process p, string command)
            {
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);

                p.StandardInput.Flush();
            }

    static void App_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                //OutPutReceivedFromThread += e.Data + "\r\n";
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data + "\r\n");
            }

            static void App_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                //OutPutReceivedFromThread += e.Data + "\r\n";
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data + "\r\n");
            }
```

Comment: Please!!!I have done whatever I knew..

Comment: Add please code of RunCommand function

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to be too complicated, or maybe that the example above doesn't illustrate your problem correctly.

i.e. You can run notepad with the following code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    }
```

So unless you need to be able to send many console lines of code to the console that you opened, or you need to read the console streams, then just try soemthing really simple. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes It's true It will open the application but In my scenario I have to open command prompt first and then I have to execute commands of my  choice. Like open notepad, close something etc..

Comment: I am able to do these task with the same code in windows 7. But the same executable does not behave properly as it behaves in win 7.

Comment: In windows 7 program starts when started using Runcommand. but in windows xp it just start and keeps it in backgroud. Never launches